# Como calcular o VPL (NPV) e o TIR (IRR) usando Javascript?

Tags: javascript, algoritmo, matemática

Estou com um projeto de TCC de viabilidade econômica usando o PHP + Javascript, pois bem, consigo calcular todos os indicadores que preciso, menos o VPL (NPV)  e o TIR (IRR), vi uma biblioteca chamada `finance.js`, mas não consegui integrar ela no meu script alguém pode me ajudar nessa?

aqui está parte do código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
String.prototype.formatMoney = function() {
    var v = this;
    if(v.indexOf('.') === -1) {
        v = v.replace(/([\d]+)/, "$1,00");
    }
    v = v.replace(/([\d]+)\.([\d]{1})$/, "$1,$20");
    v = v.replace(/([\d]+)\.([\d]{2})$/, "$1,$2");
    return v;
};
function id( el ){
    return document.getElementById( el );
}
function getMoney( el ){
    var money = id( el ).value.replace( ',', '.' );
    return parseFloat( money );
}
function soma()
{
    var total = getMoney('total_gaiolas')*getMoney('produtividade');
    id('producao_total').value =  String(total).formatMoney2();
}
</script>
```

e aqui, o que encontrei para calcular o que preciso: https://gist.github.com/ghalimi/4597900

Comment: Podias postar juntamente com a tua pergunta aquilo que já tens até agora?

Comment: pronto amigo, mas a formatação não ficou boa.

Comment: Para formatar código, basta selecionar o código e clicar no botão `{}` que se encontra por cima do editor.

Comment: Obrigado Chun, bem o código é esse, onde o mesmo imprimi o resultado automaticamente usando o onkeyup do input.

Answer (score 1):

### VPL

Segundo a fórmula da Wikipedia:

[Valor presente líquido](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valor_presente_l%C3%ADquido)

> [...] é a fórmula matemático-financeira capaz de determinar o valor presente de pagamentos futuros descontados a uma taxa de juros apropriada, menos o custo do investimento.

Portanto, o cálculo consiste em a somar os valores dos futuros pagamentos (calculados no presente) e subtrair o valor do investimento inicial.

Uma possível implementação do VPL em Javascript:

```
/*
 * Calcula o Valor Presente Líquido para
 * uma variação de período constante
 *
 * @taxa => taxa de desconto
 * @montantes => vetor com os valores com os recebimentos ou pagamentos
 * 
 */
function vpl(taxa, montantes)
{
    var ret = montantes[0];

    for (var i=1; i<montantes.length; i++)
        ret += montantes[i] / Math.pow( (1.0 + taxa), i);
    return ret;
}
```

---

### TIR

Conforme a Wikipedia:

[Taxa interna de retorno](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxa_interna_de_retorno)

> [...] é uma taxa de desconto hipotética que, quando aplicada a um fluxo de caixa, faz com que os valores das despesas, trazidos ao valor presente, seja igual aos valores dos retornos dos investimentos, também trazidos ao valor presente.

A TIR é a taxa de juros que "zera" o VPL, ou seja, `vpl(TIR, montantes) = 0`.

Para o cálculo da TIR, é necessário encontrar encontrar a raiz da equação acima.

Existem vários métodos para encontrar essa raiz:

[Algoritmo para encontrar raiz](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_para_encontrar_raiz)

Abaixo, segue um exemplo que utiliza o método da [Bisseção](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9todo_da_bisse%C3%A7%C3%A3o) (que é um dos mais simples para implementar):

```
/*
 * Calcula a Taxa Interna de Retorno (Método da Bisseção)
 *
 * @montantes => vetor com os valores
 */
function tir(montantes)
{   
    var ret = -1000000000.0;
    var juros_inicial = -1.0;
    var juros_medio = 0.0;
    var juros_final = 1.0;
    var vpl_inicial = 0.0;
    var vpl_final = 0.0;
    var vf = 0.0;
    var erro = 1e-5; // Valor mínimo que determina que a raiz foi encontrada

    // Procura um possível intervalo para a raiz
    // O looping deve terminar antes de i chegar a 100!

    for (var i=0; i<100; i++) {
        vpl_inicial = vpl(juros_inicial, montantes);
        vpl_final = vpl(juros_final, montantes);
        if (sinal(vpl_inicial) != sinal(vpl_final))
            break;
        juros_inicial -= 1.0;
        juros_final += 1.0;
    };

    // Contador que evita um looping infinito
    var count = 0;

    // Busca por Bisseção
    for (;;) {          
      var juros_medio = (juros_inicial + juros_final) / 2.0;        
      var vpl_medio = vpl(juros_medio, montantes)

      if (Math.abs(vpl_medio) <= erro) {
          // Resultado foi encontrado
          return juros_medio*100.0;
      };

      if (sinal(vpl_inicial) == sinal(vpl_medio)) {
            juros_inicial = juros_medio;
          vpl_inicial = vpl(juros_medio, montantes);          
      } else {
            juros_final = juros_medio;
          vpl_final = vpl(juros_medio, montantes);          
      };

      // Evita um possível looping infinito
      if (++count > 10000)
        throw "looping inválido";
    };

    // O algoritmo nunca deve chegar aqui.
    return ret;
};
```

[Veja funcionando no jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gomiero/p1kqcxt4/)


Abaixo, segue um link para uma página que faz esses (e outros) cálculos de forma interativa (mais didática):

[Faz a Conta](http://fazaconta.com/matematica-financeira-val-tir.htm)

Answer (score -2):

Fiz aqui um algoritmo bem preciso para achar o tão sonhado TIR.

Uma explicação breve, ele começa incrementando em 1 se for para o negativo ele inverte o sinal e divide por 10, passando a decrementar 0,1 se for para o positivo inverte o sinal e divide por 10, passa a incrementar 0,01 e por ai vai, até chegar em zero(temp entre 100 e -100)

```
function tirCalc(amounts, investment) {
    
    let tir = 0.0;
    let result = false;
    let dividend = 100;
    let actualSignal = 1; 

    if (investment > 0) investment *= -1;
    do {
        let temp = 0;
        
        for (let i = 0; i < amounts.length; i++) {
            temp += amounts[i] / Math.pow(1 + tir, i + 1);
        }
        temp += investment;

       
        if (temp < 100 && temp > -100) {
            result = true;
            break;
        }
    
        if ((temp < -100 && actualSignal > 0) || (temp > 100 && actualSignal < 0)) {
            actualSignal *= -1;
            dividend /= 10;
        }
        if (actualSignal > 0) {
            tir += dividend / 100;
        }
        if (actualSignal < 0) {
            tir -= dividend / 100;
        }
    } while (result === false);
    return (tir * 100).toFixed(2);
}
```